# Local Notification content going into a loop in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I'm trying to implement local notifications within my app. The idea is that the user is sent a notification every day at 9:00 a.m. with a different quote, but I encountered a bug where the same content of the notification is always shown, i.e. the same quote is repeated endlessly. How could I fix it? This is the code I'm using, and I tried to use a UUID for every notification that is sent, but it didn't bring improvements.

```
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound]
    notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
        (didAllow, error) in
        if !didAllow {
            print("User has declined notifications")
        }
    }

    notificationCenter.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
      if settings.authorizationStatus != .authorized {
        print("Notifications not allowed")
      }
    }
    
    let randomArrayNotificationQuote = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
    let randomArrayNotificationTitle = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myTitle.count)))
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "\(myTitle[randomArrayNotificationTitle])"
    content.body = "\(myQuotes[randomArrayNotificationQuote])"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    content.categoryIdentifier = "com.giovannifilippini.philo"
    
    // Deliver the notification
    
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 9
    dateComponents.minute = 00
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    
    let uuid = UUID().uuidString
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: uuid, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("add NotificationRequest succeeded!")
            notificationCenter.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [uuid])
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is `repeats` set to true?

Comment: Don't I use it to get the notification repeated?

Comment: Not if you want to send different notifications.

Comment: I’ve tried to change the value from true to false, but now I have issue receiving the notification in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the trigger has the repeats set to true

`let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)`

You would need to set it to false and re run this method every time you want to schedule different notification *(different content)*

In order to receive the Notification while the app is in the foreground you need to implement the `willPresent` method from the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

Here is a simple example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let userNotificaionCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1. Assign the delegate
        userNotificaionCenter.delegate = self
        scheduleNotification()
    }

    func scheduleNotification() {
      // Same notification logic that you have
    }
 }

// 2. Implement the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // This will allow the app to receive alerts and sound while in the foreground
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
}
```

Comment: I've change the value from `true` to `false` and set the trigger for sending a Notification every 60 seconds (`let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 60, repeats: false)`) for seeing the results, but I cannot receive any Notification at all

Comment: If you background the app do you see the notification after the 60 seconds?

If so you will need to implement the UNUserNotificationDelegate and to be more specific the `willPresent` method.

Look at the answer edit for the details.

Comment: And with the code added in the updated answer, the logic is the same when the app is closed, the user can receive the notification even if the app is not in the background

Comment: The app will always receive notifications when it is in the background, the `willPresent` delegate method allows you to configure how the app will handle the notification when it is in the foreground. If you don't implement this method the system will use a default implementation of this method that calls `completionHandler([.none])` which will cause the system to not present the notificaion.

For more information you can check the official [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter)

Comment: I’ve understood, and when the app it’s in the background it works great, but I’m also trying to send the notification while the app is not open in the background

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to schedule local notifications even if the app is not running? Ex. the user hasn't opened the app in a week, you still want to be sending a different notification each day? If that is the case we cannot execute code if the is not running. You could either schedule a bunch of local notifications for future dates but this doesn't seem quite right to me, I would personally use remote notifications for this and have a server send the notifications everyday day.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The app normally send local notification every day, but 1/2 days the quote inside is always the same, and I was not able to resolve this issue. Do you think that push notification will be the best?

Comment: You might be able to use a background fetch to schedule notifications  but that is not the right approach. If you cant guarantee that the app will open everyday then I would say that a push notification is  the best solution in this case. Local notifications are great for things like reminders and alarms.

Comment: I think I will just send a notification to the user by prompting it to open the app, so I will remove the issue of the repeating the quote, but at the moment I'm still trying to make sure that the notification will be delivered even if the app is closed

Comment: At the end, I just added `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` and it works perfectly even in background. Thank You for the help!